# Incrementing array values using recursion

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have an example that is only to show what I don't know how to do. When you call the function, it returns either 1 fruit, or if it rolls a 5, then I want the fruits to increment 1 time for each result it rolls and return an array, possibly going into a max recursion of like, 20 if that makes sense! :)

```
function fruitBasket(&$fruit = array()) {
    $dice = rand(1, 5);
    switch($dice) {
        case 1:
            $fruit['watermelon'] = ++$watermelon;
        break;
        case 2:
            $fruit['orange'] = ++$orange;
        break;
        // etc...
        case 5:
            for($i = 1; $i <= rand(1, 5); $i++) {
                fruitBasket($fruit);
            }
        break;
    }
    return $fruit;
}
```

Comment: oh wait, was it supposed to be in the title?

Comment: you have already written it, haven't you?

Comment: PPS: if the only question is to how to add max recursion - just add `$level` parameter

Comment: wait, so the example I wrote is correct?....

Comment: @Admiral Kunkka why did you delete your previous question .. seen something similar last week

Comment: yeah, I get undefined indexes Undefined index: watermelon

Comment: @Admiral Kunkka: http://php.net/isset + perform some research on the text message - you'll be surprised but that issue isn't something unique

Comment: @Baba, it was a mess, and flagged it for confusion

Comment: @Admiral Kunkka i don't forget codes .... what exactly do you need now

Comment: @zerkms, thanks man I guess I don't know my own php

Comment: Here `for($i = 1; $i <= rand(1, 5); $i++)` the `rand(1,5)` will be called multiple times before every execution of the loop body.

Comment: @Baba, scripting a huge project that requires tons of functions and my mind is astronomically warped from sleeping, dreaming, and fantasizing about how to code this thing hehe

Comment: your function is has a flaw ..... you need to introduce depth

Comment: It also needs to return, as in `return fruitBasket($fruit);` in `case 5:`

Comment: @Admiral Kunkka .. i still think your logic is messed up .. what exactly are you trying to achive ?

Comment: @Baba, basically this: http://i.imgur.com/yUl8b.png, for result 19-20. otherwise it would really just return a string and one random psychic power

Comment: @Admiral Kunkka seen .. not sure if this function of your is sufficient

Comment: @Baba, im not sure either now that I think about it

Comment: @Admiral Kunkka think carefully ... OPP approach would be better ... even the depth in the code below would extend more than 20 in some cases

Comment: @Baba, would it be possible to give me direction bump? :) (also, it is in OOP already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly as your description is kind of confusing and I'm unable to add a comment, but from what I do understand:

```
function fruitBasket(&$fruit = array(), $dice = 0, $depth = 1) {

    if($depth == 20)
    return $fruit;

    $dice = ($dice > 0 ? $dice : rand(1, 5));

    switch($dice) {
        case 1:
            $fruit['watermelon'] += 1;
        break;
        case 2:
            $fruit['orange'] += 1;
        break;
        // etc...
        case 5:
        $depth += 1;

            for($i = 1; $i <= rand(1, 5); $i++) {
                fruitBasket($fruit, $i, $depth);
            }
        break;
    }
    return $fruit;
}
```